# input type text not allowing input or focus

Tags: javascript, html, textinput

**Question**

I have a canvas element, above this I have a div with a text input in. The text input will not allow me to enter text or show the cursor or become focussed when clicked on.

**Steps I have taken to resolve the issue myself**

After exploring other questions similar to this I can disregard the following as the cause:

- z-index of the div being lower than the canvas (I can still see the input box)
- Not setting the positioning correctly (I have set the div to position: absolute)
- Setting select: none in the css (I do not have this)

I cannot paste all of my code because it's far too long but I can post the relevant sections:

setBuildingTileSet is the div containing the text input in question.

**css**

```
#setBuildingTileSet {
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%; 
    bottom: 50%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    background: #000;
    z-index:1;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="container"></div>

<div id="setBuildingTileSet">
  <h1>Set Building TileSet </h1>
  <p><h2>Tileset name</h2></p>
  <input id="buildingTileSetName" type="text">
</div>
```

**javaScript**

```
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
$('#container').append(canvas);
$('#container canvas')[0].id =('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;
```

I'm completely stuck and can't see why the input box will not work. Thanks for your help people :)

**Now solved - but reason why solution would cause error still unknown**

Yay, after a lot of playing around with my code I found the 'problem'. I have a mouseDown event listener which activates various things when various UI buttons are clicked on:

CoffeeScript

```
window.addEventListener 'mousedown', (e) =>
  button = e.which or e.button
  if button == 1 then @UIMouseDown(e) # Left mouse click
, false

UIMouseDown: (e) =>
  e.preventDefault() 
  ......etc
```

**Solution** I found that when I removed  e.preventDefault() then the textbox allowed me to enter text :)

**Follow up Question**  Does anyone know why e.preventDefault() would cause this behaviour?

Comment: Semicolons please! Aaah!

Comment: Sorry, actully I'm using CoffeeScript but did not want to say just in case it scared some people off.

Comment: Where is the "container" element?

Comment: It's in the html before setBuildingTileSet - I've added it now

Comment: and the css styling `#container` / the canvas ?

Comment: the #container is not styled at all, it's just used as an anchor. The only thing 'styled' on the canvas is its dimensions (updated on the question above)

Comment: I can type into the input http://jsfiddle.net/pSdk2/

Comment: I tried a fiddle myself and found that I can type so it must be a problem else where. I will post my whole html and css.

Comment: Even if I copy the full code into jsFiddle the issue is not reproducible. Could you please provide a jsFiddle demo yourself that shows the issue?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce it in a fiddle but can't. My program has over 5000 lines of code, but I can't see anything in the javascript which would even be applicable to the problem.

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that the text box works before the canvas is displayed. After the canvas is displayed it stops accepting text input.

Comment: Also if I disable the toolbar and stats it still does not work (the menu is removed at the start so is not an issue)

Comment: Couple of HTML issues. Do you have <form> tags round your input? You shouldn't have an <H2> within a <p>.

Comment: Yay - I solved the problem - please look at the edit I have made in the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your follow-up question:

`e.preventDefault()` cancels the default behaviour of an event. It makes sense if you compare it with other events:

- `click`: For `<a href="...">` elements, the browser won't navigate *like it does by default*.
- `submit`: For `<form>` elements, the browser won't submit the form *like it does by default*.
- `mousedown`: The browser will not go through the mousedown process (such as setting focus on the element the mouse cursor currently is at) *like it does by default*.